# Como mostrar en PHP una hora especifica segun el dia

Tags: php

Hola queria hacerles una pregunta, tengo un switch con los dias de la semana para mostrar segun en mi base de datos las horas en que un empleado debe marcar, todo funciona bien pero quiero que ese valor del dia sea capturado en un input para guardarlo en mi bse de datos como puedo mostrarlo en el input

ESTO ES LO QUE TENGO EN MI SWITCH

```html
$day = date("l");

switch ($day) {
    case "Sunday":
           echo $datos[0]["domingo_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Monday":
           echo $datos[0]["lunes_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Tuesday":
           echo $datos[0]["martes_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Wednesday":
           echo $datos[0]["miercoles_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Thursday":
       echo $datos[0]["jueves_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Friday":
         echo $datos[0]["viernes_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Saturday":
           echo $datos[0]["sabado_inicio"];
    break;
}
?>"
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 2):

Realmente no necesitas un `switch ... case` para esto.

Tú puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear un array con los nombres de los días
2. Obtener el número del día usando [el formato `w`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php), que trae el número del día de este modo: `0` (para domingo) hasta `6` (para sábado)
3. Según el número de día, extraes el nombre del array.

Por ejemplo:

```
$dayNames=array("domingo","lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","viernes","sabado");
$todayValue = sprintf("%s_inicio",$dayNames[date("w")]);
echo $todayValue;
```

**Salida para hoy:**

```
martes_inicio
```

Ahora puedes usar `$todayValue` para ponerlo donde quieras.

Por ejemplo, para ponerlo en un `input`:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"$todayValue\" name=\"dia\" />";
```

**Salida:**

```
<input type="text" value="martes_inicio" name="dia" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que cuando dices un INPUT es en un formulario para enviar a otra pagina donde trataras los datos

```
$day = date("l");

switch ($day) {
    case "Sunday":
           $dia = $datos[0]["domingo_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Monday":
           $dia = $datos[0]["lunes_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Tuesday":
           $dia = $datos[0]["martes_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Wednesday":
           $dia = $datos[0]["miercoles_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Thursday":
       $dia = $datos[0]["jueves_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Friday":
         $dia = $datos[0]["viernes_inicio"];
    break;
    case "Saturday":
           $dia = $datos[0]["sabado_inicio"];
    break;
}

   echo $dia;

    // Aqui deberias poner todo el FORM del formulario

   // El input con el valor de $dia
    echo "<input type='text' value='".$dia."' name='dia'>";
    
    //Cerrar formuario

    ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias  de verdad qu si